# PowerShell: retrieve number of applications in AppPool

Tags: iis, powershell, application-pool

How to retrieve the number of applications associated with a specific IIS AppPool via PowerShell command?

We can see the associated applications manually using:

```
Get-Item IIS:\AppPools\AppPoolName
```

However, if we manually want to select the `Applications` column, it is not possible. Also, the `Applications` column is not listed within `| Get-Member *`.

1. Why is the column not listed?
2. How to find the number of applications associated with a specific IIS AppPool using PowerShell?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The trick is: PowerShell established so-called "view definition files" which tell PowerShell how to format objects (e.g. whether the object is formatted as a a list or a table, which columns are displayed, etc.). Those files can be found at `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` and are all ending in `.format.ps1xml`.

To answer the original question: The file `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\WebAdministration\iisprovider.format.ps1xml` contains the view definition for the `AppPool` type which defines a calculated column looking like this:

```
<TableColumnItem>
 <ScriptBlock>
    $pn = $_.Name
    $sites = get-webconfigurationproperty "/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application[@applicationPool=`'$pn`'and @path='/']/parent::*" machine/webroot/apphost -name name
    $apps = get-webconfigurationproperty "/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application[@applicationPool=`'$pn`'and @path!='/']" machine/webroot/apphost -name path
    $arr = @()
    if ($sites -ne $null) {$arr += $sites}
    if ($apps -ne $null) {$arr += $apps}
    if ($arr.Length -gt 0) {
      $out = ""
      foreach ($s in $arr) {$out += $s.Value + "`n"}
      $out.Substring(0, $out.Length - 1)
    }
  </ScriptBlock>
</TableColumnItem>
```

This answers why the column itself is not a member of the AppPool type. The second question can be easily answered now extracting the necessary code from the "scriptlet" above:

```
$applicationsInAppPoolCount = @(Get-WebConfigurationProperty `"/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application[@applicationPool=`'$appPool`'and @path!='/']"` "machine/webroot/apphost" -name path).Count
```

Comment: Wish I could give extra points for the explanation, which is valuable in many other scenarios.

Answer (score 5):

I dealt with this same issue for many hours until finally arriving at the solution. The answer from D.R. was very helpful but it was not working for me. After some tweaks, I came up with the code below which retrieves the number of applications in an app pool.

I noticed that this part of the code `nd @path!='/'` threw off the count.

```
$appPool = "REPLACE ME with a value from your app pool"
@(Get-WebConfigurationProperty "/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application[@applicationPool=`'$appPool`']" "machine/webroot/apphost" -name path).Count
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up with the following Code (basically the same as above, but differently formatted)

```
$appPools = Get-ChildItem –Path IIS:\AppPools
foreach ($apppool in $apppools) {
  $appoolName = $apppool.Name
  [string] $NumberOfApplications = (Get-WebConfigurationProperty "/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application[@applicationPool='$appoolName']" "machine/webroot/apphost" -name path).Count
  Write-Output "AppPool name: $appoolName has $NumberOfApplications applications"
}
```

Comment: Your answer does not add anything to this thread. This should be a comment but you sadly can't post them yet ... Thank you for pointing out that the above post has a formatting issue.

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across this post searching for ways to get the active Application Pools. The information provided above was great, but I kept digging to see if there was another way get this information. I was able to find a way to do this through [Get-IISSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/get-iissite), which I used the following:

```
Get-IISSite | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Applications | Select-Object Path,ApplicationPoolName
```

I tested this on a server that only had one website, but if there are multiple sites on the server, you could also add VirtualDirectories for the Select.

I also had a need to just get a unique list of the Application Pools being used, so I did the following:

```
$appPoolInfo = Get-IISSite | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Applications | Select-Object Path,ApplicationPoolName

$appPoolInfo | Select-Object -Unique ApplicationPoolName
```

Comment: Note that this answer uses the newer IISAdministration module, which is available as of IIS 10 / Win2016, whereas the other answers use the now-legacy WebAdministration module.

Comment: Odd how it took so long to find this answer to such a simple task. Pipe a "Sort-Object  -Property Path" and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

This gives what you are looking in an array.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration;

Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools >> AppPoolDetails.txt;
$appPoolDetails = Get-Content .\AppPoolDetails.txt;
$w = ($appPoolDetails |Select-String 'State').ToString().IndexOf("State");
$w = $w -1;
$res1 = $appPoolDetails | Foreach {
    $i=0;
    $c=0; `
    while($i+$w -lt $_.length -and $c++ -lt 1) {
        $_.Substring($i,$w);$i=$i+$w-1}}
Write-Host "First Column---";   
$res1.Trim();
$j = $w + 1;    
$w = ($appPoolDetails |Select-String 'Applications').ToString().IndexOf("Applications");
$w = $w -$j;
$res2 = $appPoolDetails | Foreach {
    $i=$j;
    $c=0; `
    while($i+$w -lt $_.length -and $c++ -lt 1) {
        $_.Substring($i,$w);$i=$i+$w-1}}
Write-Host "Second Column---";  
$res2.Trim();
$lineLength=0
$appPoolDetails | Foreach {
    if($lineLength -lt $_.TrimEnd().Length )
    {
        $lineLength = $_.TrimEnd().Length;
        #Write-Host $lineLength;
    }
}

$j = ($appPoolDetails | Select-String 'Applications').ToString().IndexOf("Applications");
$w = $lineLength;
$w = $w -$j;
#Write-Host $j $w;
$res3 = $appPoolDetails | Foreach {
    $i=$j;
    $c=0; `
    while($i+$w -lt $_.length -and $c++ -lt 1) {
        $_.Substring($i,$w);$i=$i+$w-1}}
Write-Host "Third Column---";   
$res3;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but we've just had the issue issue as we need to support the old WebAdministration module - and found it was easier to iterate through the sites and applications using the Get-Site and Get-Application cmdlets.

Source code is here
https://david-homer.blogspot.com/2024/02/solved-find-web-sites-and-applications.html