# Cannot select "Applications" property from "dir IIS:\AppPools"

Tags: powershell, iis

`dir IIS:\AppPools` clearly outputs the Applications assigned to each AppPool under a "Applications" tab.

My problem is I cant seem to select just that property, plus I'm not able to locate it using `Get-Member`.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with IIS, but those members seem to be those of an application pool. Have you tried selecting an `Item` or a `ChildElements` member?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax to view most available properties and their values on an AppPool:

```powershell
ls IIS:\AppPools | where {$_.Name -eq "NameOfYourAppPool"}| fl *
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20751426/3112914), what looks like a property of an AppPool item as shown by the `Get-Item` or `Get-Child-Item` commands is actually a calculated column for display purposes. That's why it doesn't show up with Get-Member.

This calculated column uses `Get-WebConfigurationProperty` behind the scenes.

To get the web applications for a Pool as web configuration objects you can use this function that I wrote:

```
filter Get-WebApplicationForPool()
{
    $s = $_.Name
    $filter = "system.applicationHost/sites/site/application[@applicationPool='$s']"
    Push-Location .
    Set-Location "IIS:\Sites"
    Get-WebConfiguration -filter $filter -PSPath "IIS:\Sites" 
    Pop-Location
}
```

Example:

```
Set-Location IIS:\AppPools
Get-Item "DefaultAppPool" | Get-WebApplicationForPool
```